# При цикловом отправлении запросов httpclient начинает тупить

Tags: c#, httpclient, asynchttpclient

У меня программа, отправляет запрос, и парсит ответ. Таких запросов у меня 1000.
После 10-15 запросов, Httpclient начинает тупить, и отправляет запрос где-то секунд 10, и далее медленнее и медленнее.
Примерный код:

```
class a5
{
    public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task main()
    {
        for (int page = 0; Position < 1000; page++)
        {
            //int totalpages = await frist1(link);
            string full_json = await post_all_pages(page, link);
            var jsons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json5>(full_json);
            // Далее парсинг данных...
        }
    }
    // запрос 
    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> post_all_pages(int page, string link)
    {
        var Other_Link = link.Substring(link.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, link.Length - (link.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));

        var jsonrequest = "{\"PageSize\":" + 25 + ",\"PageNumber\":" + page + ",\"OrderBy\":\"PriceAsc\",\"HotelId\":null}";
        var content = new StringContent(jsonrequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var html = await client.PostAsync("https://intourist.ru/search/api/TourSearch/" + Other_Link, content);
        Console.WriteLine("{\"PageSize\":" + 25 + ",\"PageNumber\":" + page + ",\"OrderBy\":\"PriceAsc\",\"HotelId\":null}");
        Console.WriteLine(html);
        return html.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

Проблема не в библиотеке JsonConverter, а в Httpclient, т.к если делать запросы на html страницу, и её парсить, то проблема остается та же

Comment: А может на сервере стоит ограничение на количество запросов в секунду с одного IP?

Comment: @CrazyElf, если бы. У меня такая проблема получается на 3 разных сайтах, думаю такое совпадение не может быть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16194054/5045688 Попробуйте увеличить `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это .NET Core (в комментах к ответу автор это собщает), там `ServicePointManager` не влияет на `HttpClient` никак, и там по умолчанию количество соединений 10, чего вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы игнорируете `IDisposable` у классов.

Вот, исправил код метода.

```cs
public async Task main()
{
    List<Task<Json5>> tasks = new List<Task<Json5>>();
    int maxConcurrentTasks = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrentTasks))
    {
        for (int page = 0; page < 1000; page++)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            tasks.Add(post_all_pages<Json5>(page, link, semaphore));
        }

        try
        {
            Json5[] jsons = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            foreach (Json5 json in jsons)
            {
                // здесь обрабатываете полученные данные
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private async Task<T> post_all_pages<T>(int page, string link, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    try
    {
        string Other_Link = link.Substring(link.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, link.Length - (link.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));

        string jsonrequest = "{\"PageSize\":" + 25 + ",\"PageNumber\":" + page + ",\"OrderBy\":\"PriceAsc\",\"HotelId\":null}";
        using (var content = new StringContent(jsonrequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        using (var response = await client.PostAsync("https://intourist.ru/search/api/TourSearch/" + Other_Link, content))
        {
            string text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, не особо помогло. Так же продолжает все дольше и дольше отправлять запрос. Было на 5- 30 секунд, на 6- 32, на 7- 39 и тп. Был еще один метод, отправлял тоже запрос, обернул его так же в using

Comment: @vazgen5678 ну, чтобы отправить 1000 запросов последовательно, нужно время. Можно ускорить раз в 10 отправляя запросы параллельно. Я могу показать, как это сделать.

Comment: Проблема точно не в парсинге, ибо он идет 10 секунд максимум, и в консоли я уже созерцаю, как прога пытается секунд 10-15 отправить запрос, и вывести мне его в консоль. Я что-то читал об утечке данных в httclient, что после запроса, они остаются висеть, и автоматически не удаляются, но в статье решения не было. Может ли быть утечка данных?

Comment: Вы имете ввиду работу с потоками? Ну просто странно это выглядит. Каждый раз все медленнее и медленнее, от изначальной скорости. В начале отправляется моментально, дальше все медленнее, и медленнее.

Comment: @vazgen5678 скорее всего это потому что вы в консоль выводите большую кучу текста, и консоль тормозит, но это не точно. Я обновил ответ, пробуйте. И еще скажите, .NET Core у вас или .NET Framework?

Comment: Убрал весь выводимый текст в консоль, оставил только ответ на мои запросы, все так же тормозит. Использую .NET Core. Ответ ваш попробую сейчас, но вопрос. Это отправка параллельных запросов?

Comment: @vazgen5678 да, с ограничением на количество одновременно отправляемых `maxConcurrentTasks`. В .NET Core должно отработать быстро. Кстати, в .NET Core можно обойтись системным ссериализатором JSON, без `Newtonsoft.Json`. Он быстрее и поддерживает асинхронность, но это уже другая история. Чтобы переделать, мне надо увидеть ваш json ответ и класс `Json5`. Если интересно, задайте отдельный вопрос на StackOverflow, я отвечу.

Comment: @aepot А там ли вы семафор ждёте? Ведь в том месте таски ещё не выполняются и сбросить семафор будет некому. Не застрянет ли цикл? Или они сразу стартуют и я не совсем правильно всё понимаю?

Comment: @CrazyElf а с чего ему застревать? Есть ли такой шанс, что блок `try-finally` не выполнится? Это же не `Task.Run`, а по сути синхронный пуск, то есть вход в блок `try-finally` произойдет синхронно, еще до того как вернется `Task` для добавления в коллекцию. Он даже при закрытии приложения выполнится, я проверял.

Comment: Не, что `finally` выполнится это понятно, я просто раньше думал, что таски стартуют при таком подходе только когда `Task.WhenAll(tasks);` выполняться начинает. Но видимо они всё же сразу при вызовах `post_all_pages` стартуют по мере наличия потоков. Так что видимо я не прав.

Comment: @CrazyElf верно, таск "стартует" начиная с первого `await`, до первого `await` код выполняется синхронно. Но опять же `Task != Thread`, отдельных потоков там вообще может не быть. `Task` - это ожидалка, а не выполнялка :), может быть потока, может операции ввода-вывода, так что я бы не применял слово "стартует" вот так вот ко всем подряд таскам.

Comment: @aepot Вроде подставил ваш код, но увы, он так же начинает с каждым разом увеличивать время отправления запроса

Comment: @vazgen5678 но работать то стало быстрее? Вы можете обновить код в вопросе, предоставив минимальный воспроизводимый пример? То есть дать код в таком формате, чтобы я его смог вставить в свое приложение и протестировать.

Comment: @aepot да, српасибо за ваш код, работать стало гораздо быстрее. Ошибка была не в HttpClient, а в библиотеке "ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet"